# How to recover the attributes with stax

Tags: java, xml, stax

Anybody who can help me? I want to know how I can recover the values ​​of attributes with stax?
I not find methods to do this
Cordially

Answer (score 4):

If by recover, you mean get the values of, then the [`StartElement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/events/StartElement.html) event has methods to get or list attributes.